# Difference btw Chromatic number and Clique Number???

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

x(G) = chromatic number = the number of colors to color the graph.

w(G) = subgraph with K-complete subdivision graph.

Am I right?? I'm confused.

Comment: Once you correct your grammar and use the correct symbols, yes that is the gist of it.  Note that $\chi(G)\geq \omega(G)$, but it is possible for $\chi(G)$ to be strictly greater than $\omega(G)$.

Comment: If you want an explicit example of where the chromatic number is different than the clique number, consider the [wheel graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WheelGraph.html) $W_6$ which has $\chi(W_6)=4$ and $\omega(W_6)=3$.